# Project scripts not saved in the Visual Studio list

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I edit the Unity scripts, it opens up visual studio for me, and I manage the code there. Each script opened in visual studio has an x ​​next to its name, so you can remove it from view.

When I don't press the x and leave the script open in visual studio, if I close visual studio and open another script from Unity, the last script selected is shown, and alongside the previous script that I had not deleted with the x (it shows me the previous scripts that I had opened and had not removed).
What I just said happens with 6 of my projects.

The seventh however (not in order), does not behave like this. When I open a script and, without deleting it (from view, not from Unity), I close visual studio, the next time I reopen, the recent scripts are not displayed. I would like them to be displayed.

This is because I have about thirty scripts in the project, and managing the openings from visual studio is much faster than doing it from Unity, as first you have to search for the exact path of the script, and then you must also wait for it to load.

I searched for solutions and tried looking at visual-studio / unity settings, but didn't understand what may be causing this.

- I have done the "Reimport All"
- I have regenerated the project files
- I have reinstalled Unity and Visual Studio Community 2019 from the Unity Hub

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project files?  `Edit > Preferences > External Tools > [Regenerate project files]`

Comment: @hijinxbassist Yes, no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a .sln file, which references .csproj files, which contain the files within your project. These files are those listed in your solution explorer. These files are generated by Unity and are related to `Project files`. In Visual Studio in the Solution Explorer, you will see the Solution (.sln file) which contains one or more projects (.csproj), and the files within a project.

Now besides of that, Visual Studio has a lot of settings besides the actual solution and project. These settings are for instance:

- How you arrange your view in VisualStudio
- Which tabs are opened (Your question refers to the file tabs)

These settings are stored within a .suo file. These .suo files are located within a hidden directory .vs inside your project folder (next to the .sln file). Usually the .suo files and the .vs folder are part of the .gitignore list so they don't get added to the repository, because they are machine specific settings. E.g. you want your VisualStudio to be set up differently than that of another developer in your project.

I think you need to make sure that your .suo files don't get overwritten/changed by any other mechanism. For instance, if the .suo file is added to a git repository, another developer closes all the tabs, and pushes it's .suo file, and you pull that. Then after you reopen Visual Studio all the tabs will be closed. If you open 5 tabs, and push your .suo file, and the other developer pulls it, next time that developer opens VS the 5 tabs will be opened.

You can also try to delete the .vs folder to reset everything. Don't forget to make a backup though.

Comment: With this post you have made me some clarity, thanks. But the problem remains. I didn't even know this existed .suo and I'm not editing it manually. However next to the .suo in the project that gives me this problem, there is a "Browse.VC.db" which I have no idea what it is. The file is not in any of the other projects.

Comment: I just updated the answer, try to delete the .vs folder, but don't forget the backup